# Python 3 - Extract IP address and port number from dynamic webpages

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to extract IP address and port number from the this link. Here is my Python code: 
http://spys.one/free-proxy-list/FR/

```
import urllib.request
import re

url = 'http://spys.one/free-proxy-list/FR/'

req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
html = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read().decode('utf-8')

ip = re.findall( r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}',html )

# ip = re.findall( r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}:[0-9]+[0-9]',html)  # This is also not working

print (ip)
```

**Output -** 
['37.59.0.139', '212.47.239.185', '85.248.227.165', '167.114.250.199', '51.15.86.160', '212.83.164.85', '82.224.48.173']

I get only IP address but not the port numbers.

I'm expecting something like this - **'37.59.0.139:17658'**

Comment: `r'\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}:\d+'` works for me. i substituted the `[0-9]` blocks with the corresponding class `\d`. but take a look into the returned text: the string you search for is not returned in that format. instead, they put additional html-elements between the IP and the port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not work because -- aside from several issues with your regex that have been pointed out in other answers -- the website you provided displays the *port number* of each IP by executing some *javascript* in the underlying HTML code.

In order to capture each IP **and** its associated *port number*, you first need to execute the javascript so that the *port numbers* are properly printed in the HTML response (you can follow the guidelines here: [Web-scraping JavaScript page with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python)). Then you need to extract this information from the javascript-computed HTML response.

By inspecting the HTML response, I found out that each *port number* is preceded by `:</font>` and followed by `<`.

A working code snippet can be found below. I took the liberty of slightly modifying your IP-regex as only certain IP addresses were associated with a port number (other IPs were related to the *hostname* column and should be discarded) - namely, the IPs of interest are those followed by the `<script` string.

```
import dryscrape
import re

url = 'http://spys.one/free-proxy-list/FR/'



#get html with javascript
session = dryscrape.Session()
session.visit(url)
response = session.body()


#capture ip:
IP = re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}(?=<script)',response)

#capture port:
port = re.findall(r'(?<=:</font>)(.*?)(?=\<)',response)

#join IP with ports
IP_with_ports = []
for i in range(len(IP)):
    IP_with_ports.append(IP[i] + ":" + port[i])


print (IP_with_ports)
```

**OUTPUT**: ['178.32.213.128:80', '151.80.207.148:80', '134.119.223.242:80', '37.59.0.139:17459', ..., '37.59.0.139:17658']

Do note that the code above only works for the website you provided, as each website has its own logic for displaying data.

Comment: Thanks P. Shark. 
I get some error while installing dryscrape module. I follow this document to install  in my Ubuntu OS - but not successful.

https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/dryscrape/latest/dryscrape.pdf

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/xvfbwrapper.py'

Comment: Take a look at the first answer in the link I provided: you will find a link to the *dryscrape* github page, which provides instructions as to how to properly install it on an Ubuntu environment. Just make sure you execute the commands as *sudo* ;)

Comment: http://www.gatherproxy.com/proxylist/country/?c=Italy
@shark - I tried the regex for this site , but I couldn't get through. Can you please give the regex to find IP and PORT.

Comment: r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}:[0-9]+[0-9]?' 
This worked .

Answer (score 0):

First, you've a bit of a wonky part of your regex: you have `(?:`, you probably mean `(:?`. Not sure what the former means, but the latter means *zero or one `:`*

Your regex is only looking for four groupings of numbers split by `:` or `.`. You need up to five groups of numbers: `0.0.0.0:0000` = five groups. Try this instead:

```
re.findall( r'([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}(:[0-9]{2,4})?'
```

- `[0-9]{1,3}` = between one and 3 digits
- `\.` = a period (escaped, because `.` means "any character")
- `{3}` = the above needs to be repeated exactly three times
- `(:[0-9]{2,4})` a colon followed by a numeric sequence between two and four characters long. ***This is your port.***
- `?` the port is optional, it will either be there or it won't.